# Linux combine list with crunch list

Tags: linux, text-processing

I haven't been able to find a helpful answer, so I thought I'd try the experts. I have a rather long list of names; at least 400. I made a number list with crunch that goes from `00 - 99`. I need to append each name on my list with each number from the crunch list. As a short example:

Name list:

```
Anne
Barbara
```

What I want to get is:

```
Anne00
Anne01
```

through

```
Anne99
...

Barbara00
Barbara01
```

through

```
Barbara99
```

I vaguely remember there being a command to do this, but I can't for the life of me remember what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '{ for (i=0; i<100; i++) printf "%s%.2d\n", $0, i }' names_list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while read name; do for i in {00..99}; do echo ${name}${i}; done; done < name_list.txt
```